# Porting to PyQt6 QHelpEvent

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am porting a project from PyQt5 to PyQt6. I am having trouble getting the QHelpEvent code to work for tooltips on a QTextEdit.  Added ... for other code that is not relevant.

The line causing the problem:

```
help_event = QHelpEvent(event)
```

I also tried replacing event with event.type()

The error:
TypeError: QHelpEvent(QEvent.Type, QPoint, QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QHelpEvent'

The Tooltip event filter class:

```
class ToolTipEventFilter(QtCore.QObject):
...
    def eventFilter(self, receiver, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.ToolTip:
            help_event = QHelpEvent(event)
            cursor = receiver.cursorForPosition(help_event.pos())
            pos = cursor.position()
            receiver.setToolTip("")
            ...
```

If anyone can help that would be great. The Qt C++ documentation is not helping me:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qhelpevent.html#details

Comment: It seems like PyQt5 used to allow creating a new QHelpEvent based on the one provided as argument. In any case, the error is clear: you're using a wrong argument type. Even if it's aimed for C++, the constructor of the documentation is exactly the same, so just use `event.type(), event.pos(), event.globalPos()`.

Comment: Now that I'm reading again your code, that is QHelpEvent creation wasn't even required on PyQt5, as the original event already provided those functions.

Comment: Yes. I think I copied that code from an older example, and it worked at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @musicamante that works perfectly.

```
def eventFilter(self, receiver, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.ToolTip:
            cursor = receiver.cursorForPosition(event.pos())
            pos = cursor.position()
            receiver.setToolTip("")
```